# Загрузчик не видит систему на новом диске

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, bios, загрузчик

Добрый день. Преобрёл новый SSD(220) и решил поставить на него Linux Mint. Отсоединил все диски, подсоединил новый, поставил, но bios не видит вообще, что на этом диске есть система. На старый SDD(110) диск, на котором раньше стояла винда, система встает нормально, и отображается в загрузчике BIOS.

Подсоединил оба диска, запустил систему со старого диска, сделал `sudo fdisk -l`, чтобы проверить, вдруг разметка различается, оказалось что разметка одинакова. Что сделать чтобы bios видел систему со второго диска?

P.S. Mint переустанавливал кучу раз, и через UEFI, и без нее, без резульатно. Биос всеравно ее не видит

Вывод `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Диск /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 байтов, 234441648 секторов
Единицы измерения: секторов из 1 * 512 = 512 байтов
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0x3d4bc537

Устр-во    Загрузочный     Start Конец Секторы  Size Id Тип
/dev/sda1  *                2048 205158399 205156352 97,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2              205160446 234440703  29280258   14G  5 Расширенный
/dev/sda5              205160448 234440703  29280256   14G 82 Linux своп / Solaris


Диск /dev/sdb: 223,6 GiB, 240065183744 байтов, 468877312 секторов
Единицы измерения: секторов из 1 * 512 = 512 байтов
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0x396a5733

Устр-во    Загрузочный     Start Конец Секторы   Size Id Тип
/dev/sdb1  *                2048 439592959 439590912 209,6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2              439595006 468875263  29280258    14G  5 Расширенный
/dev/sdb5              439595008 468875263  29280256    14G 82 Linux своп / Solaris
```

Еще заметил, что в системе, запущенной со старого SSD(110)отображается 3 диска, один на котором текущая система, другой на котором система которая не запускается, и третий, не открывающийся, названный "KINGSTON..."(название диска SSD(110)) как в boot меню .

Сброс CMOS, через кнопку на материнке, тоже не помог.

Comment: Последнее замечание очень интересно. Как будто новый ssd может видится как 2 устройства и биос видит не то. По крайней мере этот "третий диск" заставляет задуматься. Интересно, что в /proc/partitions и что в логах загрузки ядра, что оно там увидело ...

Comment: ну третий диск это название того на котором "запускающаяся система". Т.е. на запущенной системе два диска, один из которых не открывается, и третий с другой не запускающейся системой

Comment: в /proc/partitions все те же диски что и в `fdisk`

Comment: Вы не *fdisk* смотрите, а *gdisk* или как там для GPT называется.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ tail /sys/block/*/removable` при обоих подключенных блочных устройствах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!

Косяк был в том, что моя материанская [Asrock p67 extreme4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/P67%20Extreme4/index.asp) имеет 4 порта SATA3, два из которых без поддержки AHCI. Как раз в один из этих портов и был подключен новый SSD, поэтому загрузчик BIOS его не видел, а записывать и читать с него можно было.